# What does "#define STR(a) #a" do?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm reading the phoneME's source code. It's a FOSS JavaME implementation. It's written in C++, and I stumbled upon this:

```
// Makes a string of the argument (which is not macro-expanded)
#define STR(a) #a
```

I know C and C++, but I never read something like this. What does the `#` in `#a` do?

Also, in the same file, there's:

```
// Makes a string of the macro expansion of a
#define XSTR(a) STR(a)
```

I mean, what's the use of defining a new macro, if all it does is calling an existing macro?

The source code is in https://phoneme.dev.java.net/source/browse/phoneme/releases/phoneme_feature-mr2-rel-b23/cldc/src/vm/share/utilities/GlobalDefinitions.hpp?rev=5525&view=markup. You can find it with a CTRL+F.

Comment: Apparently this (specifically the combination of the `STR` and `XSTR` macros) is called the "double stringize trick". There is a very good explanation in the question [How, exactly, does the double-stringize trick work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the first definition, `#a` means to print the macro argument as a string. This will turn, e.g. `STR(foo)` into `"foo"`, but it won't do macro-expansion on its arguments.

The second definition doesn't add anything to the first, but by passing its argument to another macro, it forces full macro expansion of its argument. So `XSTR(expr)` creates a string of `expr` with all macros fully expanded.

Answer (score 5):

# is the stringizing operator. The preprocessor makes a string out of the parameter.

Say you have:

```
STR(MyClass);
```

It would be preprocessed as:

```
"MyClass";
```

The level of indirection (using XSTR()) has to do with macro expansion rules.

Answer (score 4):

The `#a` is referred to as the [stringizer operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx).  It takes the formal parameter, in this case `a`, and turns it in to a string by enclosing it in double quotes.

So if you have:

```
string s = STR("my quoted string");
cout << s;
```

The output would be:

```
"my quoted string"
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but I think "stringizer" is Microsoft-only; it's normally the "stringify" operator, and the process is called "stringification"

Comment: If you're going to make up words, then "stringify" and "stringise" are just as cromulent as each other. I propose "stringulate".

Comment: @John, I believe you meant: `string s = STR(my quoted string);`, i.e., *without* the quotes (and with the semicolon).

Comment: @John Dibling, @Michael Mrozek: At least in C++, that section of the standard is titled `[cpp.stringize]`.

Comment: @Alok:  No, I meant the quotes.  The point is that the stringizer, or whatever you prefer to call it as personally I couldn't care less, will return a quoted string.  But you're right about the semicolon.  Added.

Comment: @John, yeah I don't know what I was thinking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should know that this pair of macros is actually fairly common. The first does exactly what the comment says -- it turns an argument into a string by enclosing it in double quotes.

The second is used to cause macro expansion of the argument. You typically use them together something like this:

```
#define a value_a

printf("%s", XSTR(a));
```

The macro expansion will expand `a` out to `string_a`, and the stringify will turn that into a string, so the output will be `value_a`.