# c preprocessor passing multiple arguments as one

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

The C preprocessor is passing multiple arguments as if they were a single argument. I feel pretty sure the problem is how we are calling the `untouchable` macro, but every attempt we have made to alter the `first` macro has failed to produce the desired result. Here is a complete code sample with comments that explain what happens and what we want to happen:

```
//this can be changed, but it must remain a #define to be of any use to us
#define first a,b,c

// v all code below this line cannot be altered (it's outside of our control)

#define untouchable(name, c1, c2, c3) \
    wchar_t name[] = \
    { \
        quote(c1), \
        quote(c2), \
        quote(c3) \
    }

#define quote(c) L#@c

// ^ all code above this line cannot be altered (it's outside of our control)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    static untouchable(mrNess, first);

    // the line above is precompiled to:
    // static wchar_t mrNess[] = { L'a,b,c', L, L };

    // whereas we want:
    // static wchar_t mrNess[] = { L'a', L'b', L'c' };

    return 0;
}
```

We are compiling in Windows under VisualStudio.

Comment: What does `@` do in `L#@c`?

Comment: It surrounds its argument in single quotes as opposed to double quotes. It's Microsoft specific.

Answer (score 6):

When the preprocessor encounters the invocation of a function-like macro, it first identifies the arguments, next completely macro-expands them<sup>*</sup>, and last replaces the macro invocation with its replacement list, with the expanded arguments inserted at the appropriate places.  The expansion of macro `first` is (or would be) performed too late for the preprocessor to recognize in the expansion separate arguments to macro `untouchable()`.  You'll need to find another way.

One possibility is to insert a level of indirection:

```
#define untouch_wrap(name, args) untouchable(name, args)

static untouch_wrap(mrNess, first);
```

There, `first` is expanded before `untouch_wrap`, so that when the result is re-scanned for further macros to replace, the resulting invocation of `untouchable()` has the correct number of arguments.

That does rely on the second argument to `untouch_wrap()` to expand to a comma-separated list of exactly three members.  It would be cleaner and more flexible to define `untouch_wrap()` like this:

```
#define untouch_wrap(name, ...) untouchable(name, __VA_ARGS__)
```

... but MSVC's handling of variadic macros is non-conforming, and I suspect that it would trip over that.

---

<sup>*</sup> Expansion is suppressed for arguments that are operands of the preprocessor's stringification (`#`) and token-pasting (`##`) operators.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be how you define `first`. You pass `first` to the `untouchable` macro, *but it is obviously not expanded at that time*.

So do not use the `first` macro like that and pass `a`, `b`, and `c` as single arguments to the macro. Then you will get what you want.

### Update

But there is some hope:

```
#define UT_HELPER(a,b,c,d) untouchable(a,b,c,d)
#define UT(x, y) UT_HELPER(x, y)
#define first a, b, c
static UT(mrNess, first);
```

It is similar to the solution found in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8588232/95954), so I can't claim having thought it up myself.

Note that

```
#define quote(s) L#@s
```

doesn't work in my compiler, so I can't fully test it. I simply tried with

```
#define quote(s) L###s
```

and that worked.

I hope this gets you going for the real, more complicated macros you seem to have.

Comment: If you mean call it using `untouchable(mrNess, a, b, c)`, that is precisely what we can't do. We need to use a `#define` in the call.

Comment: What do you mean you can't do that? What hinders you?

Comment: We are refactoring a large codebase, and part of that is to make these macros easier to understand. If we use `a, b, c` it is more complex than using `first` (in reality I have simplified it here, there are actually 13 arguments, so it would be `a, b, c, d, e, f, ..., m` as opposed to simply `first`).

Comment: @alice see [here](https://github.com/MirBSD/mksh/blob/03ae72e654c218cf85064da8b763e482b4218cba/mbsdint.h#L392) for a practical example

Answer (score 1):

[C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), 6.10.3.1 Argument Substitution:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have
>   been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the
>   replacement list, unless preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or
>   followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the
>   corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing
>   tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the
>   preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

Look at how this is expanded:

```
#define first a,b,c
#define untouchable(name, c1, c2, c3) \
    wchar_t name[] = \
    { \
        quote(c1), \
        quote(c2), \
        quote(c3) \
    }

untouchable(foo,first,c,d)
```

into:

```
$ gcc -E foo.c
...

wchar_t foo[] = { quote(a,b,c), quote(c), quote(d) }
```

First the arguments are identified, so the untouchable parameter first becomes c1. Only after they are identified are they are expanded and then substituted into the macro body. `first -> c1 -> a,b,c`. Now in the macro body c1 is replaced by `a,b,c`.

I skipped the quote macro from the question because it is illegal on my compiler.

Comment: This is what confuses me when I read the documentation. All those substitutions and expansions! If I am reading what you have written right though, are you saying at the point the `a,b,c` from `first` gets to `untouchable` they are unalterably a single token?

Comment: Yes. If you try `untouchable(foo,first)` you get an error because the macro only sees two parameters but was expecting 4.