# Why i am not getting the expected output in the following c programme?

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “#define STR(a) #a” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534070/what-does-define-stra-a-do)
>   [Macros evaluation in c programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776750/macros-evaluation-in-c-programming-language)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define f(a,b) a##b
#define g(a)   #a
#define h(a) g(a)

int main()
{
      printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));
      printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
      return 0;
 }
```

I was expecting the output to be same for both the printf. But what I am getting is different(given below)

```
12
f(1,2)
```

can someone explain what is the reason and why is it happening in detail?

Comment: Is everyone still cracking their brains at this? :D

Comment: Your question is exactly same as another question given link below.
Please check it out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776750/macros-evaluation-in-c-programming-language

Comment: @Sanjay I was actually expecting f(1,2) f(1,2)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore

`#define Str(x) #x`

`#define Xstr(x) Str(x)`

`#define OP plus`

`char *opname = Xstr(OP);`
This code sets opname to "plus" rather than "OP".

Answer (score 3):

I extended your program with an additional line

```
printf("%d\n",f(1,2));
```

which, in turn, results into

```
printf("%d\n",12);
```

(called with `gcc -E`).

Your two lines result into

```
printf("%s\n","12");
printf("%s\n","f(1,2)");
```

What happens here?

`f(1,2)` is clear - `1` and `2` just get sticked together.

`g(something)` just reproduces `something` as a string, without treating it specially -> `"f(1,2)"`.

`h(something)`, in turn, lets the result of `g(something)` expand.

Answer (score 1):

C standard states that macro arguments aren't expanded if they are stringified or concatenated. That is why `g(YOUR_MACRO)` YOUR_MACRO isn't expanded. However in `h(YOUR_MACRO)` case - h() does stringification **indirectly** and so it complies with C macro arguments expansion rules and is expanded further.

Answer (score 0):

**First one:**

```
 printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));
```

becomes:

```
  g(12)
```

which in turn becomes

```
  "12"
```

**Second one:**

```
printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
```

becomes

```
"f(1,2)"
```

since `#` converts the argument to a string parameter.