# Nested Macro : Order of Expansion

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why i am not getting the expected output in the following c programme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062271/why-i-am-not-getting-the-expected-output-in-the-following-c-programme)

i am having a doubt in order of evaluation of macros.like for the following code i am not able to understand the ouput:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define f(a,b) a##b
#define g(a) #a
#define h(a) g(a) 
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));
    printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
12
f(1,2)
```

why not f is getting expanded first before g in the second printf ?

Comment: This (exact!) question was asked here more than once.

Comment: thnx guys...got my answer from the duplicate posts.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a consequence of how macros are expanded, and has an impact on self-referential macros... This is quite nicely explained in detail in the [GNU CPP manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros)