# How does this crazy C macro hack work?

Tags: c, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How, exactly, does the double-stringize trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work)

I came across [this](http://everything2.com/title/stringize+macro+macro+hack) the other day - can someone tell me how it works?

> A simple way to stringize a C
>   preprocessor constant, in all
>   compilers conforming to ANSI C (or any
>   C++ compiler).
>
> Suppose you have a header file
>   containing a constant like #define
>   FIELD1_WIDTH 17. Now you want to build
>   the string "%17s", which tells printf
>   the width of the field. If you're a
>   wimp, you can use a format string
>   "%*d" and pass FIELD1_WIDTH in as the
>   first parameter. But that doesn't
>   solve other problems. You might also
>   want to put an identifier string in
>   your program giving the values of
>   important constants, which strings can
>   find. In other words, you have to be
>   able to translate FIELD1_WIDTH into
>   "17". And because you'll be doing it
>   with some constant surrounding text,
>   you'd like a macro to do it for you.
>
> This is so easy as barely to be worth
>   mentioning. Actually, I lied. It's
>   impossible to guess the horrible hack
>   that does it. Just do this:
>
> ```
> #define STR(x)   #x
> #define XSTR(x)  STR(x)
> ```
>
> Then using XSTR(FIELD1_WIDTH) yields the string
>   "17". The rôle of XSTR is particularly
>   mysterious.
>
> hint: STR(FIELD1_WIDTH) expands to "FIELD1_WIDTH", which is
>   not what you want...

thanks :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work

Comment: I don't see anything 'crazy' about it.

Comment: This is a very well known technique with all rewrite-based (macro) languages (m4 and LaTeX for example in addition to cpp).  You're just forcing argument `x` to be macro substituted before it's stringified. After the first expansion of `XSTR` you have `STR(FIELD1_WIDTH)`.  The macro processor then expands `FIELD1_WIDTH` to `17` (because it's required to eagerly expand arguments before the macro call that binds the argument) then finally expands `STR(17)`.