# How to print the #define statement?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

How can I get `cerr` to print `5 < 6` as opposed to `statement_`? I have access to Boost and Qt.

```
using namespace std;

#define some_func( statement_ )               \
  if( ! statement_ )                          \
  {                                           \
    throw runtime_error( "statement_" );      \
  }                                           \

int main()
{
  try
  {
    some_func( 5 < 6 );
  }
  catch(std::exception& e)
  {
    cerr << e.what();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the stringize operator:

```
throw runtime_error(# statement_);
```

If `statement_` may be a macro, you'll want to use the [double stringize trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC16).

and here's the final working code =):

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

#define some_func( statement_ )              \
  if( ! statement_ )                         \
  {                                          \
    throw std::runtime_error( #statement_ ); \
/* Note: #, no quotes!       ^^^^^^^^^^  */  \
  }                                          \

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  try
  {
    some_func( 5 < 6 );
  }
  catch(std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what();
  }
}
```