# Concatenate C macro definition string to literal strings

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Let the first row be:

```
#define TAG_LEN 32
```

Now, I need to concatenate it with a literal string constant; something like that:

```
puts("Blah" [insert your answer] TAG_LEN); // I need "Blah32".
```

Comment: `32` is not a string, so that won't work. You're going to have to *call* a macro to do the magic.

Comment: Check the double stringify trick here: [Stringify macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define STR_NOEXPAND(tokens) # tokens
#define STR(tokens) STR_NOEXPAND(tokens)
puts("Blah" STR(TAG_LEN));
```

Comment: Caution : underscore-prefixed identifiers are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
printf("Blah%d", TAG_LEN);
```

or if you have a string

```
char *yourString;// initiate it with your value

printf("Blah%s%d",yourString, TAG_LEN);
```

Comment: Literal strings concatenation required here but not dynamic arrays copying