# How to expand macro value to wide string?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012, macros

Let's say I have a macro

```
#define CLASS_NAME ItemsList
```

Later I would like to use the value of it, not as a symbol, but as wide string. And my problems begin. When I simply write (in a regular C++ code, not in macro definition):

```
L#CLASS_NAME
```

compiler gives me an error, saying token `#` was not expected here. When I write proxy for it

```
#define WSTRING(S) L#S
```

and use it

```
WSTRING(CLASS_NAME)
```

I will get wide string with content "CLASS_NAME". I would like to expand macro, meaning getting its value, not converting the macro name.

So how to do it properly (Visual Studio 2012)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `L"ItemsList"` then you can use:

```
#define CONCAT2(X, Y) X##Y
#define CONCAT(X, Y) CONCAT2(X, Y)
#define STRINGIFY2(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY2(X)
#define WIDEN(X) CONCAT(L, STRINGIFY(X))
```

And then write `WIDEN(CLASS_NAME)`.

Comment: You have a typo on the definition, `WIDEN` should expand to `WIDEN2`. But the more important issue is that `WIDEN(CLASS_NAME)` as written will expand to L"CLASS_NAME", because the `#` is on the first level of expansion. It has to be on the second level of expansion to actually expand the parameter.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work

Comment: @JanHudec Right you are.

Comment: Thank you, but even with fixed type I still get `CLASS_NAME` as the result.

Comment: Million thanks (I wouldn't solve it by myself, no way :-D), it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! And thanks also to the author of the question for having asked it! I could never have figured it out by myself. Just, it is a bit a disappoint to me that c++ does not allow any easier and more compact/intuitive way to do a simple job as expanding a macro to a wide string!