# Remove a value from an enum without changing the other values

Tags: c, enums, refactoring, c-preprocessor

I have several enums that serve as type constants. For example:

```
enum item_type {
  street,
  town,
  lake,
  border,
...
}
```

The enum values are used in code to designate object types, and are written out to disk as part of data files. This mostly works well, but there is one drawback:

There is no way to remove an enum member (because it is no longer used) without changing the integer values of all subsequent members. So any such change would make the code incompatible with existing data files.

Is there some good technique for avoiding this problem? Maybe some preprocessor trick?

The only solution I can think of is to explicitly set all the integer values. While that would work, it is hard to read and manage for big enums.

Note: This problem comes from the source code of [Navit](http://www.navit-project.org/), which uses several such "type enums" (though they are actually hidden behind some macros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up declaring a macro `UNUSED`, which expands to
`UNUSED_<linenumber>`. Then unused enum values can just be replaced by
`UNUSED`. The macro expands to a unique identifier on each line it is
used because otherwise the compiler would complain about duplicate enum
entries it were used multiple times inside one enum.

This is slightly ugly if you have many "gaps". Still, I chose this
solution over simonc's solution because it easy to read (keeps the regular enum values free of visual
clutter like `three=zero+2`) and does not require magic numbers.
Admittedly this only makes sense if the gaps are few and far between.
For large gaps simonc's solution looks better.

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNUSED UNUSED_P(__LINE__)
#define UNUSED_P(x) UNUSED_P2(x)
#define UNUSED_P2(x) UNUSED_##x

enum e {
  zero,
  UNUSED,
  UNUSED,
  three,
};

int main(void){
  printf("int value of 'three': %d\n",three);
  return 0;
}
```

The double replacement is adapted from, among others, this question:
[c++ - How, exactly, does the double-stringize trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work) .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove items very rarely, you could do something like

```
enum item_type {
  street,
  town,
  //lake,
  border = town+2,
...
}
```

i.e. only explicitly assign a value to the item immediately following the one you remove.

Since compatibility is very important to you, it'd be more reliable to just bite the bullet and explicitly number all items

```
enum item_type {
  street = 0,
  town   = 1,
  //lake   = 2,
  border = 3,
...
}
```