# refactor 'execute and log' pattern

Tags: c++, c, function, logging, refactoring

I found myself keep following the same pattern again and again:

```
if((return_code = doFoo1(...)) != CODE_OK) {
    log("useful log message based on return code");
    // very likely to return an error code. 
}

// continue

if((return_code = doFoo2(...)) != CODE_OK) {
    log("useful log message based on return code");
    // very likely to return an error code. 
}
```

Any insight how to avoid this annoying pattern and keep the logic clean?

Comment: Write a macro in C or a template function in C++?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the thing is I don't even want to write the useful log message there. is it possible to auto log message like: "function bar in filexxx at line 123 return error code 1, which means blablabla. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to tackle this, here's a basic one:

```
bool CheckAndLog( int code )
{
  if( code == CODE_OK )
    return true;
  log( "<some error based on code>" );
  return false;
}

if( !CheckAndLog( doFoo1(...) ) )
  return;
```

If you also need the return code for later use you could return it from CheckAndLog, or have it as a pass-by-reference argument, or even make CheckAndLog into a class which stores the latest error code and which you instantiate with the (possibly scoped) logger instance to use.

**update** if you want file and line info you need the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros and to save yourself from typing them all over the place a simple macro is sufficient:

```
bool CheckAndLog( int code, const char* file, unsigned line )
{
  if( code == CODE_OK )
    return true;
  std::cerr <<  "file " << file << " line " << line
            << "<errormessage>" << std::endl;
  return false;
}

#define CHECK( what ) (CheckAndLog( what, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))
```

Take it one step further to get the called function into that: since it is available as the macro argument it is expanded as such by the preprocessor. Meaning if you type `CHECK( foobar( 65 ) )` the `what` argument is seen literally as `foobar( 65 )` and not as it's return value. Which is ideal since the preprocessor can also [turn that into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work):

```
bool CheckAndLog( int code, const char* desc, const char* file, unsigned line )
{
  if( code == CODE_OK )
    return true;
  std::cerr <<  desc << " from file " << file << " line " << line
            << "<errormessage>" << std::endl;
  return false;
}

#define STRINGIZE1( x ) #x
#define STRINGIZE( x ) STRINGIZE1( x )
#define CHECK( what ) (CheckAndLog( what, STRINGIZE( what ), __FILE__, __LINE__ ))
```

I'd advise against using `CHECK` as the name for your macro though since it is more often than not used by unit test libraries as well. Also take great care never to redefine your macro (by accident or on purpose) to something like `#define CHECK( what ) (true)` because that would mean if you write 
`CHECK( foobar( 65 ) )`, the function will simply never be called.

Comment: I am thinking the question for a while. Is it possible to write a class, a function or macro that could auto generate some error message there. for example, u call CHECK(foo(a, b)), it might log output "foo from filexxx at line:123 return error 1, error means: blablalbla" and if u call CHECK(bar(a)) it might output similar message.