# how should I concatenate macros in C?

Tags: android, c, logging, macros

I'm trying to create a log helper, and want to concatenate the line number to the log info.

I want to accomplish a Log like this: (" -l:" + **LINE** + args)

```
05-22 15:04:16.626 21270-22699/com.mydomain.myproject D/myfile.c: -l:5 myloginfo ...
```

This is what I have in my loghelper.h file:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#include <android/log.h>
#define FILETAG (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1  : __FILE__)
#define LINEIDENTIFIER ' -l:'
#define TOKENAPPEND(x, y, z) x##y##z
#define APPENDLINE(x, y, z) TOKENAPPEND(x, y, z)
#define printf(fmt,args...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, FILETAG , fmt, APPENDLINE(LINEIDENTIFIER, __LINE__, ##args))
#define printfe(fmt,args...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, FILETAG, fmt, APPENDLINE(LINEIDENTIFIER, __LINE__, ##args))
#define printfw(fmt,args...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, FILETAG, fmt, APPENDLINE(LINEIDENTIFIER, __LINE__, ##args))
#endif
```

calling from **myfile.c** like this:

```
#include "loghelper.h"

...

printf(" myloginfo %s", "...");
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: pasting formed '' -l:'52', an invalid preprocessing token
error: expected ')'
error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
error: use of undeclared identifier 'APPENDLINE'
error: pasting formed '57"success!"', an invalid preprocessing token
error: expected ')'
```

**Q: What am I doing wrong? What should I change to make it work?**

Comment: After fixing the spaces before the macro parameter lists, you should also [double-stringize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work) `__LINE__` to get a string literal that you can concatenate

Comment: @lurker you are right that is one of the problems, I will update de question with that fixed and the new error I'm getting

Comment: @M Oehm I didn't grasp what you meant by double-stringize, isn't that what I'm doing with the APPENDLINE and TOKENAPPEND macros? Would you please explain to me again?

Comment: No. That's token pasting, and it won't help you here. I'll write an answer.

Comment: Ok great, I'm just learning macros in c and if you can explain will be of much help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use the token pasting operator `##` where you can't use it. Token pasting can be used to create new tokens, usually new identifiers:

```
#define MY(X) my_##X     // MY(func) -> my_func
```

Here, you want to concatenate string literals. There are two things to note here:

- You don't need the preprocessor to concatenate string literals. The C syntax will join adjacent string literals: `"to" "gether"` will be treated like `"together"`.
- The `__LINE__` macro expands to an integer, so you must turn it into a string literal. The stringizing operator `#` will not work on the special token `__LINE__`, so you must write a macro to stringize. If you do that, you get the string literal `"__LINE__"`, which isn't very useful. Use [double stringizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work), i.e. add one more level of indirection, to get the actual line mumber as string.

Putting all this into practice, a simple logging macro could look like this:

```
#define M_STR_(x) #x
#define M_STR(x) M_STR_(x)

#define LOG(...) fprintf(stderr, "Line " M_STR(__LINE__) ": " __VA_ARGS__)
```

I've used a shorter example here for te sake of simplicity. Things to note are:

- I've used the standard `...` and `__VA_ARGS__` notation here and I haven't split up the format string and the arguments in the macro parameters list. That way, the macro will work without printing arguments and you don't need the non-standard `##__VA_ARGS__` to suppress the lone comma.
- This macro will only work when the format string is a string literal, as it ought to be. The Format string `"%s"` will be expanded to `"Line " "12" ": " "%s"`.
- Prepending string literals to the format string is easy, but it is more complicated to append to it, for example if you want to end the format string with a new line. You could use your approach to separate `fmt` from the args, but it might be easier to stick to the simple approach and have the macro expand to two print statements: One for the formatted string and another one for the new-line. (But make sure to [wrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros), so that these two commands cannot be separated.)

Finally, the method applied to your `printf` repclacement:

```
#define printf(...)                                       \
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, FILETAG,       \
    "-l " M_STR(__LINE__) ": " __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Great, that makes sense to me and works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code based on *@M Oehm*'s answer, for if you are wondering how it ended up.

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#include <android/log.h>
#define FILETAG (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1  : __FILE__)
#define GETLINE_(x) #x
#define GETLINE(x) GETLINE_(x)
#define printf(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, FILETAG , "-l" GETLINE(__LINE__) ": " __VA_ARGS__)
#define printfe(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, FILETAG,  "-l" GETLINE(__LINE__) ": " __VA_ARGS__)
#define printfw(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, FILETAG, "-l" GETLINE(__LINE__) ": " __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```