# How to use preprocessor macro in GCC basic asm?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I need to write a **basic asm** code in GCC, which uses an immediate constant defined in a header file. I know how to do this in **extended asm**, but how can I do it in basic asm, which does not have any input and output parameters?

Comment: I cannot use extended asm because the function has _naked_ attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [stringize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work) type *C* preprocessor macro to convert a constant value to a string. You can then use that string to construct a basic inline assembly statement. An example would be:

```
#define STRINGIZE1(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE1(x)

#define STACK_ADDR 0x1000

int main()
{
    asm ("movl $" STRINGIZE(STACK_ADDR) ", %esp");

    return 0;
}
```

This example should generate this assembly instruction:

```
movl $0x1000, %esp
```

Note: this code is not meant to be a runnable example.